# Why is the create() function in node js not creating the data in the mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I basically wrote a code to check if the data is existing or not in the mongoDB and if it is then I'm trying to create a new document and if it is then I'm basically updating the same document
this is my controller code
Controller.js

```
try {
  
    
    console.log(req.body)
    let data = await IITSchema.findOne({ Email })
    console.log(data)
    if (data) {
      const updateFormData = await IITSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
        { Email },
        {
          PhoneNumber,
          YearofGrad: YearofGrad,
          FullName,
          Evidence,
          CollegeName: CollegeName,
          user: SaveUserData._id,
          City: City,
          GraduationDegree: GraduationDegree,
          Department: Department,
          placement_time: placement_time,
          targeted_companies: targeted_companies,
          interests,
          In_what_areas_do_you_need_our_help,
          Others,
        }
      );
     return res.status(200).json({ message: "update", data: updateFormData });

    } else {
      // if (!SaveFormData) {
      const newformdata = new IITSchema({
        
      })
      const newFormData = await IITSchema.create({
        Email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        PhoneNumber,
        YearofGrad: YearofGrad,
        FullName,
        Evidence,
        CollegeName: CollegeName,
        // user: user._id,
        City: City,
        GraduationDegree: GraduationDegree,
        Department: Department,
        placement_time: placement_time,
        targeted_companies: targeted_companies,
        interests,
        In_what_areas_do_you_need_our_help,
        Others,
      });
       return res.status(200).json({ message: "create", data: newFormData });
    }
       
     

  
  } catch {
    (err) => {
      console.log("error from New Step Form", err);
      res.json({ error: err });
    };
  }
```

this is my Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const IITSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  FullName: String,
  Email: String,
  interests: { type: [String] },
  CollegeName: String,
  YearofGrad: String,
  password: String,
  Evidence: Boolean,
  Department: String,
  GraduationDegree: String,
  In_what_areas_do_you_need_our_help: { type: [String] },
  City: String,
  placement_time: String,
  targeted_companies: String,
  PhoneNumber: String,

  Others: String,

  referral: { type: String, default: null },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("iitbombay", IITSchema);
```

and this is the req.body that I'm getting from the front end

```
{
  FullName: 'Mohammed Khan',
  Email: 'aven.farhan@gmail.com',
  password: 'asdfsadfsd',
  Evidence: true,
  PhoneNumber: '+919515876470',
  CollegeName: '   GURU PRAKASH B.ED. COLLEGE , Kaimur (Bhabua), Bihar',
  YearofGrad: 2023,
  GraduationDegree: 'Bsc',
  Department: 'CSE',
  City: 'Adoni',
  In_what_areas_do_you_need_our_help: [ 'Complete Placement Preparation' ],
  targeted_companies: 'FAANG (Facebook, Amazon, Apple, Netflix and Google)',
  placement_time: 'Less than 1 month',
  interests: [ 'Data Science / Analytics' ]
}
```

this is the code that I'm using to send the data to the backend i.e node js and mongodb

```
await fetch(BASE_URL + "/iitbfform", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(newData),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("Response from firstForm", data);
            });
```

the code is completely fine but the document is not getting saved
it would mean alot if some can point out the error that I'm doing over here

Comment: Does the `iitbombays`collection exist?

Comment: yes it does, because some time it works,some time it doesnt

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't save it.

Comment: now its like even If remove everything and just try to create() a document I'm not able to do it